# Can't update two tables in one Query

Tags: mysql

I've got two Queries to Update two tables:

First Table

```
UPDATE user_info SET `location` = ".$locationid.", `looking_for` = ".$lookingfor." WHERE `user_info`.`user_id` =  ".$infoid.";
```

Second Table

```
UPDATE user_personality SET `personality` = '".$changedescription."' WHERE `user_personality`.`user_info_id` =  ".$infoid.";
```

And I'm trying to merge those two Queries, using the same statement.

```
UPDATE user_info, user_personality
SET user_info.location = ".$locationid.", user_info.`looking_for` = ".$lookingfor.", user_personality.personality = '".$changedescription."'
WHERE  `user_info`.`user_id` =  ".$infoid."
AND `user_personality`.`user_info_id` =  ".$infoid."
```

I'm not receiving any error message, but is not updating.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest using `JOIN` syntax, instead of table lists.

Comment: try a select with the same conditions? maybe you don't have any matching records in one of the tables, and your conditions require that there be records in both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess...

```
"
UPDATE user_info i
  JOIN user_personality p
    ON p.user_info_id = i.user_id
   SET i.location = $locationid
     , i.looking_for =  '$lookingfor'
     , p.personality = '$changedescription'
 WHERE i.user_id = $infoid;
";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the 2 table fields equal to *each other* in the where clause it should work, so I believe you'd change your where clause to:

```
WHERE  `user_info`.`user_id` = `user_personality`.`user_info_id`
AND `user_info`.`user_id` =  ".$infoid."
```

MySQL definitely supports updating multiple tables, so the where clause that works for a multi table select statement should also work for an update.